# Ffmpeg to convert gif to webm with reverse function

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a gif file to webm file using the below which works fine however I’m wondering is it also possible to reverse it as well using ffmpeg or would I need to reverse it using imagemagick first then cover it using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i your_gif.gif -c:v libvpx -crf 12 -b:v 500K output.webm
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The script posted here might help you.
This one seems to be in bash but ripping the commands should work on Windows as well.
https://github.com/WhatIsThisImNotGoodWithComputers/ffmpeg-webm-scripts

These are the relevant lines of code (note that they need to edited for your setup):

```
ffmpeg -i "${INPUT_FILE}" -ss $START_TIME -to $TO_TIME -an -qscale 1 $TEMP_FOLDER/%06d.jpg
cat $(ls -r $TEMP_FOLDER/*jpg) | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -r 25 -i - -c:v libvpx -crf 20 -b:v $FRAMERATE $CROPSCALE -threads 0 -an $OUTPUT_FILE
```

You basically have to convert all stills to jpgs and then back into webm, but in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

From `ffmpeg --help`, you can see what codecs `ffmpeg` supports with `ffmpeg -codecs`.  `ffmpeg -codecs|grep -i gif` on mine says it supports gif.

`ffmpeg` checks extensions to get file type if you don't override,

```
ffmpeg -i onoz.webm onoz.gif
```

does the trick just fine.