# Use GIFs in <video> tag, or use videos in <img> tags

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've been trying to get a way of showing both `gif`s and `video`s (`.mp4`, `.ogg`, `.webm`) **within the same tag**.

So, if it is within a `<video>`tag I would only  change the source or the `<source>` to a `gif` or `video` and show it accordingly.

Unfortunately I'm not finding anything consensual that would allow doing this.

Does anyone got a simple solution before I move on to the hardest ones?

Comment: Not possible. And if you’re able to change the `source` of a video element, then instead “toggling” between a `video` and an `img` element by showing one and hiding the other should not be that much “harder” either …

Comment: Just an opinion here, but GIFs are very heavy images, if that makes sense. A webm video of the same content is much smaller and can be used in a `<video>` tag with controls and audio disabled and looping turned on, essentially giving users the same experience. Definitely a better way to go, IMO.

Comment: @BrianBennett And do you know how to convert gifs to webm on the go?

Comment: It's something you would need to do beforehand. You can use a GUI program like Handbrake to run a conversion or a command line program like ffmpeg. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133402/ffmpeg-to-convert-gif-to-webm-with-reverse-function) has a command for ffmpeg that will work (ignore the answer...use the question code).

Answer (score 6):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

> The HTML `<video>` element is used to embed video content. It may
>   contain several video sources, represented using the `src` attribute or
>   the  element; the browser will choose the most suitable one.

Therefore `gif` - not a video content  - is **NOT** an option to be used in `<video>` tag

Here is the list of [supported formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements) for `<video>` and `<audio>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `poster` attribute in `<video>` tag to show gif files. but it is not a complete solution, because you can not use them (video and gif) together.