# Background video in Node.js 13

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to set up a gif as a background,I get does it not work:

In the code Import GridMatrix and extract the src from it, then I use the video tag to try to render it on fullscreen.

```
import React from 'react';
import GridMatrix from '../assets/gridMatrix.gif';

function Home() {

    return (
        <div>
            <video
                className="matrix-bg fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full z-[-1] object-cover"
                autoPlay
                loop
                muted
            >
                <source
                    src={GridMatrix.src}
                    type="video/gif"
                />
            </video>
            <main className="container mx-auto py-10 px-4 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mb-8 text-white text-center">
                    UNS Demo
                </h1>
                <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                    Login
                </button>

            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIF files are not video files and the MIME type for them is image/gif. The `<video>` tag [will not render them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31330780/316310).

You can embed images using `<img src={GridMatrix.src} />` or set it as a background-*image* with CSS on an element.

Nowadays, websites often embed what they call 'GIFs' that are *actually* video files, but notice that those are often `.webm` or `.mp4` files, both being video formats, thus compatible with `<video>`.